# non-nullable reference types и default(T)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

вот такой метод

```
public TResult FirstOrDefault()
{
        ...
      return default;                
}
```

Ругается

> Warning CS8603    Possible null reference return

Если же попытаться сделать так

```
public TResult? FirstOrDefault()
```

то ошибка компиляции

> Error CS8627  A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint

Но я не могу повесить ограничение. Этот метод должен делать то, что следует из его названия и принимать как ссылочные, так и значимые типы.

Как указать компилятору на "тут все нормально, отстань"?

Comment: `default` -> `default!`?

Comment: @PetSerAl сработало...только логика плывет. Ведь ! гласит "я знаю, что там не null", а в случае default как раз именно что нулл какой нибудь

Comment: Можно подавить предупреждение: [#pragma warning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы так уверены в своем коде, то просто заглушите *(проигнорируйте)* предупреждение.

```
public TResult FirstOrDefault()
{
        ...
#pragma warning disable 8603
      return default;
#pragma warning restore 8603
}
```

Comment: проще #nullable disable...#nullable enable только это трудный путь