# c# 8 non-nullable types и null!

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

По мотивам [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/972316/non-nullable-reference-types-%D0%B8-defaultt)

Есть старый код, который перевожу на c#8 и там есть методы

```
void MethodName<T>(T value) => ...
и много вызовов вида
MethodName(null);
```

который может принимать как классы, так и структуры, а значит мы не можем сделать так

```
 void MethodName<T?>(T? value) => ...
```

потому что потребует указания типа T, а мы не можем указать where T: class, struct

Приходится давить варнинг при вызове

```
#nullable disable
MethodName(null)
#nullable enable
```

Но оказалось что работает и так

```
MethodName(null!)
```

Это вообще нормально? Это недоработка компилятора (бета все-таки)? Или же ! означает не просто "уверен тут не null", а более широкое "с этим значение все хорошо, проходи мимо"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно одному из примеров в документации, постфиксный оператор `!` может использоваться, чтобы показать вашу осведомленность об использовании нулевой ссылки (в том числе и представленной непосредственно литералом `null`).

[! (null-forgiving) operator (C# reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

> One of the use cases of the null-forgiving operator is in testing the argument validation logic. For example, consider the following class:
>
> ```
> #nullable enable
> public class Person
> {
>     public Person(string name) => Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
>
>     public string Name { get; }
> }
> ```
>
> Using the MSTest test framework, you can create the following test for the validation logic in the constructor:
>
> ```
> [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
> public void NullNameShouldThrowTest()
> {
>     var person = new Person(null!);
> }
> ```
>
> Without the null-forgiving operator, the compiler generates the following warning for the preceding code: `Warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.` With the use of the null-forgiving operator, you let the compiler know that passing null is expected and shouldn't be warned about.

Перевод последнего абзаца:

> При отсутствии оператора, допускающего значение null, компилятор сгенерирует следующее предупреждение: `Warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.` С помощью использования этого оператора Вы даёте компилятору знать о том, что передача литерала `null` осознана и не должна вызывать беспокойства.

Так что это не недоработка компилятора, а всего лишь один из вариантов использования. Например, для проверки поведения метода в юнит-тестировании.